Can $\mathrm{tr}(\boldsymbol{A}^k)$ be expressed using only eigenvalues of $\boldsymbol{A}$'s symmetric and skew-symmetric parts?
Let $\boldsymbol{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, and $\boldsymbol{N} := \dfrac{1}{2}(\boldsymbol{A} + \boldsymbol{A}^{\mathrm{T}}), \boldsymbol{\Omega} := \dfrac{1}{2}(\boldsymbol{A} - \boldsymbol{A}^{\mathrm{T}})$. Let the eigenvalues of $\boldsymbol{A}$ be $\lambda_{i}$, the eigenvalues of $\boldsymbol{N}$ be $n_{i}$, and the eigenvalues of $\boldsymbol{\Omega}$ be $\omega_{i}$. We want to express $\mathrm{tr}(\boldsymbol{A}^k)$ in terms of $n_i$ and $\omega_i$. For example, $\mathrm{tr}(\boldsymbol{A}) = \mathrm{tr}(\dfrac{1}{2}(\boldsymbol{A} + \boldsymbol{A}^{\mathrm{T}})) = \mathrm{tr}(\boldsymbol{N}) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}n_{i}$, and $\mathrm{tr}(\boldsymbol{A}^2) = \mathrm{tr}(\boldsymbol{N}^2) + \mathrm{tr}(\boldsymbol{\Omega}^2) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}n_{i}^2 - \sum_{i = 1}^{n}|\omega_{i}|^2$.  Note that the trace of the square of a real skew-symmetric matrix is the sum of the squares of its eigenvalues.  Since the eigenvalues are purely imaginary, their squares are negative real numbers.
For the case $k = 2$, I used the fact that $\mathrm{tr}(AB) = \mathrm{tr}(BA)$, and the canonical forms of real symmetric and real skew-symmetric matrices under orthogonal similarity. However, for the case $k\geq 3$, I am stuck. Is there a good way to calculate this?

$\mathrm{tr}(\boldsymbol{A}^2) = \mathrm{tr}(\boldsymbol{N}^2) + \mathrm{tr}(\boldsymbol{\Omega}^2) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}n_{i}^2 - \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\omega_{i}^2$ with $\omega_i$ the eigenvalues of $\mathbf \Omega$ is false

Error have been fixed.

Consider $A = \begin{pmatrix}
a & 0 & 0\
0 & b & y\
0 & -y &  c
\end{pmatrix}$.  We get: $$\mathrm{tr}(A^k) = 2^{-k} \left(2^k a^k+\left(-\sqrt{(b-c)^2-4 y^2}+b+c\right)^k+\left(\sqrt{(b-c)^2-4 y^2}+b+c\right)^k\right)$$
The expression should be symmetrical in ${a,b,c}$, (ie. invariant to their permutation) but it is not. So you can't recover it from the eigenvalues of the symmetric and skew-symmetric parts.   You can obtain working expressions for $k = 2$ (and any $n$) or $n = 2$ (and any $k$), but not general ones.

Oh, indeed, I made an incorrect question.

you still have "Note that the trace of the square of a real skew-symmetric matrix is the negative sum of the squares of its eigenvalues.  Since the eigenvalues are purely imaginary, their squares are negative real numbers." which is erroneous and contradicts your edited equation.

Error have been fixed.

It is not possible as shown by the counter-example of @user3257842 in the comments. Formally,
Claim : There is no function $f : \mathbb{R}^3 \times (i\mathbb{R})^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ symmetric in the first three, and in the last three variables such that for all matrix $A = N + \Omega \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$,
$$
\mathbb{tr}(A^3) = f(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3,\mu_1,\mu_2,\mu_3),
$$
where the $\lambda_i$ and the $\mu_i$ are the eigenvalues of $N$ and $\Omega$.
Assume the function $f$ exists. Since you can express $\mathrm{tr}(A)$ and $\mathrm{tr}(A^2)$ in function of the eigenvalues of $N$ and $\Omega$ and you can express $\det(A)$ in function of $\mathrm{tr}(A)$, $\mathrm{tr}(A^2)$ and $\mathrm{tr}(A^3)$, then we can build a symmetric function $g : \mathbb{R}^3 \times (i\mathbb{R})^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $A$,
$$
\det(A) = g(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3,\mu_1,\mu_2,\mu_3).
$$
With,
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
a & 0 & 0\\
0 & b & y\\
0 & -y & c
\end{pmatrix},
$$
you obtain, $a(bc + y^2) = g(a,b,c,0,iy,-iy)$ so,
$$
a(bc + y^2) = g(a,b,c,0,iy,-iy) = g(b,a,c,0,iy,-iy) = b(ac + y^2),
$$
so
$$
ay^2 = by^2,
$$
but this expression is false for $a = 1$, $b = -1$, $y = 1$, leading to a contradiction.
